# How to connect to database in zf

Tags: zend-framework

Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_News' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testZend\application\controllers\IndexController.php  on line 14
i cannot connect model class with index controller
how  can i solve the problem
how will the Model Application_Model_News class identified in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your models are located under /application/models/ directory, then you should use Model_ prefix in model class name (not Application_Model_)
So your problem is not about DB connection.